# gdi32.GetObject doesn't work when running 64-bit

Tags: c#, .net, 64-bit, pinvoke, gdi+

This code works fine when running 32-bit. But when I switch to 64-bit the `GetObject` method does not work and `BITMAP` struct is empty.

```
IntPtr hBmp = ObtainValidBitmapHandleFromSystem();
BITMAP bmpData = new BITMAP();
/* BITMAP consists of four 32bit ints,
 * two 16 bit uints and one IntPtr */
 * 4 + sizeof(UInt16) * 2 + IntPtr.Size;
int cbBuffer = sizeof(Int32) * 4 + sizeof(UInt16) * 2 + IntPtr.Size;
NativeMethods.GetObject(hBmp, cbBuffer, out bmpData);

Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(bmpData.Width, bmpData.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
```

The native method implementation:

```
private static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("gdi32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal extern static int GetObject(
        IntPtr hgdiobj,     // handle to graphics object
        int cbBuffer,       // size of buffer for object information
        out BITMAP lpvObject    // Should be IntPtr, but we know we will use it only for BITMAP.
    );
}
```

The BITMAP structure implementation (removed documentation to keep code compact):

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct BITMAP
{
    public Int32 Type;
    public Int32 Width;
    public Int32 Height;
    public Int32 WidthBytes;
    public UInt16 Planes;
    public UInt16 BitsPixel;
    public IntPtr Bits;
}
```

The idea behind this code is fully described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627376/use-native-hbitmap-in-c-sharp-while-preserving-alpha-channel-transparency).

At first I thought that the issue is caused by different size of `IntPtr` resulting in different size of `cbBuffer`, but it seems that this is not the case as changing `cbBuffer` size did not help.

What is the correct way to use GDI's `GetObject` method on 64-bit system?

Comment: How does NativeMethods look like ?

Comment: @Tigran I've edited my question to include part of the `NativeMethods` class.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Isn't there any exception?

Comment: @KingKing as I said in the question: "BITMAP struct is empty". There is no exception or noting. After call to `GetObject` the `BITMAP` struct is still empty (all it's values are zero).

Comment: What's the return code value for GetObject?

Comment: I think you should check the result returned by GetObject first, there is a documentation on it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144904(v=vs.85).aspx I really don't understand what you have from the handle returned by ObtainValidBitmapHandleFromSystem(), I think the hBmp should point to a Bitmap's memory which certainly contains data.

Comment: @KingKing hBmp is an HBITMAP and that's an opaque pointer

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've googled for opaque pointer and it seems that it is originated from the world of C, I can understand it a bit however what does it matter the fact that it (maybe the underlying pointer) should point to some memory address at which we can obtain data. Thanks.

Comment: @KingKing But the point is that only the system knows the layout of that data. It's not something you ever read.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan OK, thank you. That's why it's called 'opaque'. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
cbBuffer = sizeof(Int32) * 4 + sizeof(UInt16) * 2 + IntPtr.Size;
```

That works on the 32 bit version because the alignment of the struct has no padding. But on the 64 bit version, there are 4 bytes of padding before the pointer. So `cbBuffer` is 4 bytes short.

That's the problem. The solution is to stop calculating the size yourself and use [`Marshal.SizeOf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.sizeof.aspx) which is designed for this very purpose.

Comment: if so wouldn's be enough to use compbination of [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)] and [FieldOffset(OFFSET_NUMBER)] ?

Comment: @Tigran That's used when the standard alignment patterns don't fit the actual layout of your struct. Those scenarios are rare for C structs. They are invariably aligned, sometimes packed. Both of which can be handled by `LayoutKind.Sequential`. The main use for `LayoutKind.Explicit` is to make a C union. That's when you use `FieldOffset(0)` for all members. P.S. Thanks for the upvote and the grown up way you handled to your now deleted answer. Many users here would have reacted less well!

Comment: Who deleted the first answer? What kind of privilege is so powerful?

Comment: @KingKing The author/owner of the answer deleted it. The owner can always do that, unless the answer has been accepted. Other than that, if an answer has negative scores, then 3 delete votes from high community mods will delete it. And posts can always be deleted by diamond mods.

Comment: Thanks @DavidHeffernan - this works as expected... now I have to figure out why on 64-bit my bitmaps with alpha channel get that weird psychedelic colors :/